# Is it possible to create a task using workflow on particular stage move in the business process flow in dynamic crm 2016?

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, dynamics-crm-2016

I have added new stages to Sales stage option sets which are used in the business process flow for Opportunity.

Is it possible to create a task using workflow only when we move to a particular stage (i.e."Develop") in the business process flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to trigger a workflow when the stage in a Business Process Flow changes.

A Business Process Flow has fields called [*ProcessId* and *StageId*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481586.aspx#Anchor_3). *ProcessId* is the GUID of the BPF, while *StageId* is the GUID of the stage in the BPF. In the UI *StageId* is called *Process Stage*.

You can register a workflow to *Start when: Record fields change* and select *Process Stage*. At the beginning of the workflow, add a *Check Condition* step and see whether *Process Stage (Process Stage)* -> *Process Stage Name* equals "Develop".

Comment: I have already tried the above solution but it didn't work for me. It was creating a task on every stage move.

Comment: I am able to create a task based on business process flow stage move using the above steps. Actually i was looking into the Process Sessions of workflow and in that i found many tasks (Task for every stage) . And yes it will create view record for every stage move in view but it will create a task based on condition.

Thank You Henrik.